# Combining Lines

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have been working on this illustration for quite sometime now, I sketched it and was able to trace it via Illustrator, the first of **many** problems I uncounted was that I was not able to combine 1 separate line with an closed object! Rather the the outline of the body (or figure) is just one separate thing and the lines are another separate thing,I still want to refine the figure and add more lines to give it detail. I just need help in just combining all of the lines to make one object.

[image]

Comment: I'm not entirely following what you're asking. When you say that you "traced" it in Illustrator, do you mean that you scanned your pen/pencil drawing and used Illustrator's "Live Trace" feature? Even if you did this and don't know how to separate/combine the lines, I think this would be a great opportunity to draw this right in Illustrator. You could use the above image in the file and just draw a new set of vector lines right over it in Illustrator.

Comment: Additionally, perhaps post either a screen capture from Illustrator with the line and anchor points shown or even post a link for the file itself so we can actually look at it in Illustrator.

Answer (score 1):

Once you're done drawing all the lines you can outline the stroke then use Unite to join them together into a compound shape. While they're still lines, though, they will be separate.